# Spring controller get request/response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How do I get the request/response that I can setcookie?  Additionally, at the end of this method, how can I can redirect to another page?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dosomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RETURNREDIRECTOBJ dosomething() throws IOException {
    ....
    return returnredirectpagejsp;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dosomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView dosomething(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws IOException {
    // setup your Cookie here
    response.setCookie(cookie)
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("redirect:/other-page");

    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Usually spring is configure with the view suffix, so you should not include it in the view name (html)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know we could turn it into a `HttpServlet#service()` method :-) One point to note is we can't use the `@RequestMapping` anymore when these two parameters are declared.

Answer (score 7):

1. Just pass it as argument: `public String doSomething(HttpServletRequest request)`. You can pass both the request and response, or each of them individually.
2. return the `String` `"redirect:/viewname"` (most often without the `.jsp` suffix)

For both questions, check [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html), section "15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types"

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply `@Autowire`.  For example:

```
@Autowired 
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Though HttpServletRequest is request-scoped bean, it does not require your controller to be request scoped, as for HttpServletRequest Spring will generate a proxy HttpServletRequest which is aware how to get the actual instance of request.

Comment: @zygimantus No it does not work with response. There are some hacks to have it injected though (not recommended), check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984054/autowired-httpservletresponse

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String method(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        Cookie newCookie = new Cookie("key", "value");
        response.addCookie(newCookie);
        return "redirect:/newurl";
    }
```