# @Autowired HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I'm looking for a way to autowire `HttpServletResponse`. It doesn't work with spring out of the box, but I've found [this description](http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/06/injecting-httpservletresponse-into-spring-mvc-request-scoped-interceptors/). This works but is sort of annoying, in that spring obviously has a mechanism to make objects request scoped (i.e. `HttpServletRequest`) and this seems to be a hack bolted on top.

Is there a way to hook into the same mechanism that spring uses for `HttpServletRequest`? And, any idea why spring team decided to only make `HttpServletRequest` autowire capable (and excluded `HttpServletResponse`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps there is some workaround, but it's not that obvious, because it's not the way it's meant to be. Spring MVC is meant to have singleton `@Controller` beans that provide `@RequestMapping` methods which take the request and response as arguments.

If you need the response in another place (the service layer) - don't do it. The response should not go beyond the web (controller) layer.

To inject the response, you need:
- to store the response in a `ThreadLocal`
- to make a factory bean that returns the current response

About [the example code you showed -](http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/06/injecting-httpservletresponse-into-spring-mvc-request-scoped-interceptors/)  I'm not sure if you are not going to need the factory bean to return a proxy (implementing `HttpServletResponse`), which in turn to return the current response. And it gets rather complicated.

But ultimately - you should not do that. If you need to intercept multiple controller invocations, use an mvc-interceptor. If you really need to use an aspect, you can get the response if it is passed as argument to the intercepted method.

Comment: Not so fast: What about an `@Aspect` that that is meant to wrap the `@Controller`. The "not the way it's meant to be" argument doesn't explain why HttpServletRequest is autowire capable and HttpServletResponse is not either.

Comment: Use interceptors for that. They see the response

Comment: The request - I don't know why they made it injectable. I'll look for a way to inject response and will let ypu know

Comment: Are you saying that spring's AOP support is insufficient for the specific use case of wrapping controllers that want access to the response?!

Comment: First, there are interceptors. Then you can get the method arguments (hence the response)

Comment: The link you provided was the one I provided originally in my question. I think it's a hack. Spring could easily make the response available in the same way as it makes the request available. My question was, can I hook into that mechanism somehow, rather than re-invent it.

Comment: @Kevin - I don't think you can.

Comment: I'll mark your answer correct--not because I like it, but because it accurately reflects the way it is.

Comment: you said that "The response should not go beyond the web"
But what if i need to alter response coockie by my inner logic ?

Comment: An example like voipp's: you need to refresh the OAuth2 token. If you use RestTemplate you can catch the unauthorized failure, request a new token and update your cookie that stores that.

Comment: What about 'request' scoped beans? Shouldn't be able to autowire response? They are web layer specific.

Answer (score 5):

Can you simply include the request in the method handle?

```
@RequestMapping(method=Method.GET, value="myUrl")
public String doGet(HttpServletResponse response){//spring will put the response in for you
  ... 
}
```

Comment: He's looking for the response, in a non-Controller bean. (I think).

Comment: Good point, updated for the sake of him winting the response.  Though Bozho has the better response.