# How to get response on url specified in UPI Hyperlink payment

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to pay through a UPI hyperlink like

```
upi://pay?pa=abc@upi&pn=payeeName&tr=1234&tn=Pay%20to%20payeeName&am=1&mam=1&cu=INR&url=https://test.com/payment/orderId=123456
```

- I am sending above link through sms
- When I click on link it shows UPI application list as option
- I have selected BHIM app (also tried other applications)
- Then completed payment, till now it works fine.

After the UPI payment is done, the Spring controller which handles the "callback" request to https://test.com/payment/orderId=12345, is not getting called.

So how to get response of UPI Hyperlink payment in Java correctly?

Edit:

This is the controller method. I have also tried `@GetMapping` instead of `@PostMapping`.

```
@PostMapping("/payment")
public ModelAndView credPayment(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String key = request.getParameter("orderId");
    String txnId = request.getParameter("txnId");
    String responseCode = request.getParameter("responseCode");
    String approvalRefNo = request.getParameter("ApprovalRefNo");
    String status = request.getParameter("Status");
    String txnRef = request.getParameter("txnRef");
    System.out.println("Parameter Names");
    while (request.getParameterNames().hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(request.getParameterNames().nextElement());
    }

    System.out.println("Header Names");
    while (request.getHeaderNames().hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(request.getHeaderNames().nextElement());
    }

    System.out.println("txnId : "+txnId);
    System.out.println("responseCode : "+responseCode);
    System.out.println("ApprovalRefNo : "+approvalRefNo);
    System.out.println("Status : "+status);
    System.out.println("txnRef : "+txnRef);

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: is it a GET or a POST request you are expecting? Is the controller behind the link also made? What is the code behind the Controller of "PaymentController.java" ? is there a route? can you call it explicitly by using postman, and sending the expected variables? what Response do you see when you call it yourself?

Comment: Payment Done Successfully. I have try both GET and POST for redirect url [https://test.com/payment/orderId=123456] and I can call it explicitly also. I am just doing `System.out.println("Hello");` inside controller

Comment: can you provide code snippet?

Comment: @NileshPatel, can you please confirm that you are really able to call `/payment/orderId=123456` directly from a browser for example? Because based on your examples, it shouldn't be possible - look at the MyTwoCents' answer...

Comment: @Petr Bodnár, I can call `/payment/orderId=123456` from web and its working fine

Comment: @Petr Bodnár, I have tried your answer but it wont work

Comment: @NileshPatel, ok then. Maybe this could help: a) check / describe how you setup & use the UPI, step by step scenario of the behavior (when and how the redirect to `url` is done / expected to be done), b) how you register / allow your `url` to be called, c) check that your server's certificate is valid - have you tried with plain `http` in `url`?

Comment: - I am sending link through sms
- when I click on link it shows UPI application list as option 
- I have selected BHIM app (also tried other applications) 
- Then completed payment, till now it works.
- After payment completion redirect url should be called. but I don't know they call redirect url or not. If they call url then I am unable to handle it on given code.

Comment: Hi, @NileshPatel, Can you able to get the transaction status from callback URL. I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri myAction = Uri.parse("upi://pay?pa=******@****&pn="+"*******"+"&mc="+"&tid="+transaction_ref_id +"&tr="
                +transaction_ref_id +"&tn=Pay%20to%20*****%20*****%20App&am="+"1.00"+"&mam=null&cu=INR&url=https://mystar.com/orderid="+sOrderId);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(myAction);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

*******************
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String res = data.getStringExtra("response");
                if (res.contains("Status=SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Payment successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Payment was not successful! Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Payment was not successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL parameter in the payment link **is not a callback URL**. And currently no payment app is using it for that purpose.

The URL is only meant to provide transaction information to the payer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, your redirect URL is

```
https://test.com/payment/orderId=123456
```

And when this is called, you need to get order id value in your controller.

Then try changing your method to something like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/payment/{order}")
public ModelAndView credPayment(@PathVariable("order") String order, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(order); // prints orderId=123456
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**Issue:**

You have configured your URL mapping as `/payment` only, so anything after that will get excluded from this mapping, eg: `/payment/sdfdsfs`

Comment: Based on the information given in the OP, this is by far the most relevant and useful answer so far. An alternative solution is to use a properly url-encoded form of `https://test.com/payment?orderId=123456` as the value of the `url` parameter passed to the UPI URL. Still, the basic problem and its solution remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is with you method signature. Try to add the response to your method parameter so you can get the response object. Change your method to:

```
public ModelAndView credPayment(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

Comment: it should https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564465/spring-controller-get-request-response 
 If you try to run your request on postman what the response you get? it is not good way to rate -1 for someone offering you a help

Comment: check this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467848/how-to-get-http-response-code-for-a-url-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Have you ever work with UPI hyperlink payment? your link is not about UPI Hyperlink. @Fateh

Comment: it does not matter in the end it is HTTP request, right ?

Comment: It does matter because There is question that they are calling our url or not? and if they are calling our url then how to handle that request?